# How to repeat a TALL table header on each page in Chrome?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

First time poster =)

I'm printing a long table and want to repeat the table header on each page. I'm not having a problem until the height of the `<thead>` gets to a certain height - in Chrome 87.0.4280.88 it appears to be 242px with default margins. At 242px high or more, the header only prints once on the first page. Shrinking the page margins when printing does give me some more room to play with, but is there any workaround to this so I can print a taller `<thead>` on every page without adjusting the margins? I can't seem to find any documentation on this, I'm quite stumped.

```
<table>
  <thead>
    <th style='height: 242px'>if this was 241px it would print on every page</th>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr><td>anything</td></tr> <!-- do this 100 times, or enough it goes to multiple pages -->
  </tbody>
</table>
```

Thanks in advance!